# wpf databinding not updating from a property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want movieinformation updated in a some textboxes depending on the selected movie

I have

```
public Movie SelectedMovie { get; set; }
```

in my viewmodel which is what my datacontext is set at

And whenever a movie is selected in my list it updates "SelectedMovie"

But only the first movie updates the textblock

```
<TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedMovie.Name}" FontSize="17" />
```

(The one selected when the application loads)

So not really sure why its not changing the text when I select a new movie in the list?

Movie class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MovieDB3.Models
{
    class Movie : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Movie(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        private string name;
        public string Name 
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                InvokePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        private double rating;
        public double Rating
        {
            get { return rating; }
            set 
            { 
                rating = value;
                InvokePropertyChanged("Rating");
            }
        }

        public DateTime Release { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan Runtime { get; set; }
        public String Trailer { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void InvokePropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventArgs e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            PropertyChangedEventHandler changed = PropertyChanged;

            if (changed != null) changed(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to fire PropertyChanged event in the setter of the SelectedMovie property in order to notify the binding that something has changed:

```
private Movie selectedMovie;

public Movie SelectedMovie
{
    get
    {
        return selectedMovie;
    }
    set
    {
        selectedMovie = value;
        InvokePropertyChanged("SelectedMovie");
    }
}
```